# How to write special characters in template literals?

Tags: javascript, template-literals

I am using template literals for a string in javascript and want to insert special characters like & and $ with hex code (&lettersandnumbers;) like you would in normal strings but it doesn't read it. I tried putting it in ${} but that didn't help either. Is there a way to write it?

Comment: `&lettersandnumbers;` is used for **HTML markup**, not for JavaScript string literals (unless the string literals are being inserted with `innerHTML` into the HTML later, or something like that)

Comment: sure, e.g. `\u{42F}` gives you `Я`

Answer (score 6):

See [Escape notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#escape_notation) on MDN:

| Code | Output |
| --- | --- |
| \0 | U+0000 NULL character |
| ' | single quote |
| " | double quote |
| \ | backslash |
| \n | new line |
| \r | carriage return |
| \v | vertical tab |
| \t | tab |
| \b | backspace |
| \f | form feed |
| \uXXXX (where XXXX is 4 hex digits; range of 0x0000–0xFFFF) | UTF-16 code unit / Unicode code point between U+0000 and U+FFFF |
| \u{X} ... \u{XXXXXX} (where X…XXXXXX is 1–6 hex digits; range of 0x0–0x10FFFF) | UTF-32 code unit / Unicode code point between U+0000 and U+10FFFF |
| \xXX (where XX is 2 hex digits; range of 0x00–0xFF) | ISO-8859-1 character / Unicode code point between U+0000 and U+00FF |

Answer (score 2):

You can use escape character (backslash - \) to treat special characters as normal ones.

```js
const text = `text\$somemoretext\&end`;
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `&lettersandnumbers;` escape sequence is for HTML, not JavaScript strings. In javascript strings, there are different ways to represent a special character. In your case, you do not need to escape the character "$" or "&".

To represent a character in a string with a hexadecimal code, do this:`` `I like \x24\x24\x24!` `` which evaluates to "I like $$$!".